# How best to move heated air within a long room

Tags: heating

My studio is 12.5 m x 5 m wide (about 41 feet x 16.5 feet). A 7.5 kW capacity reverse-cycle air-conditioner, mounted on one of the short walls, heats the room. The ceiling of mystudio is the floor of the studio above. How can I best encourage the circulation of warm air from one end of the studio to the other?

Comment: Is the studio an open floor plan or does it have walls/something to break it up?  Fan/s will probably be easiest to move air.  Duct work sounds like it might be too much.

Comment: Probably some sort of [oscillating fan](https://www.google.com/search?q=oscillating+fan&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsb_6Usy1ZC7H7gxhX5KfzzuspLl0A%3A1668348566839&ei=lvpwY8fWMre5qtsPltSCSA&ved=0ahUKEwjH-b_dqqv7AhW3nGoFHRaqAAkQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=oscillating+fan).

Comment: Yes, it is a long open floor plan.

Answer (score 4):

A fan. Possibly with a duct. Or multiple fans.

Common commercial product for the job you likely won't want to listen to is a "Horizontal Air Flow" ([HAF](https://farm-energy.extension.org/horizontal-air-flow-is-best-for-greenhouse-air-circulation/)) (or "Movement") fan for a greenhouse, which have similar temperature balancing issues. They are not usually optimized for quiet operation.

Ceiling fans are generally quiet, and will help push the heated air down off the ceiling, and spread it around some, but won't do a great job at bulk movement lengthwise.

An inline fan sized for the largest duct you can tolerate running along the room could be quite effective, and with the right inline fan, not very noisy. I'd lean towards having it suck from the floor at the far end and dump on the heat pump head (so, bringing cooler air from the far end) but you could also have it pull heated air from the heat pump head end and dump it at the far end.

A pair of fans, one on each of the the long walls, ~3m from the respective end wall blowing opposite directions, each away from the wall it's near (to generate a circulating flow around the room) might be effective with no duct involved, especially if you also have some ceiling fans to push heated air downwards. That would be taking the greenhouse HAF concept, but using fans you can tolerate having running in your studio space. If the heat pump head is on one side of its short wall, you might only need one such fan at the opposite end on the opposite side to encourage circulation, with the heat pump head being the "other fan" for circulation.

You can experiment with portable fans in that application.

Answer (score 0):

Would think a ceiling fan or two.  Or two box fans blow at each other at opposite ends of the room